# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+2\pi i\xi}e^{2\pi i\xi x}d\xi $?

Tags: fourier-transform

How does one integrate $w(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+2\pi i\xi}e^{2\pi i\xi x}d\xi$ ?

This should be $w(x)=e^{-x}u(x)$ where $u(x)$ is the Heaviside unit step function.

In other words, for $x<0$,  $w(x)=0$, and for $x\geq 0$, $w(x)=e^{-x}$.

I want to know how to do the integral. Thank you for teaching me!

Comment: I feel like the residue theorem can be used here after passing to a complex integral, but I would have to work it myself.

Comment: The integral does not converge classically. However, hint: $w'(x)+w(x) = \delta(x)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi, maybe better said as "the integral does not converge _absolutely_...", though, yes, the not-so-good-convergence is the main issue in any rigorous evaluation. :)

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you for your advice!  I will study the residue theorem and contour integration and try to solve this!

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your hint! That helps a lot.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it might be instructive to present a solution that relies on classical real analysis only.  We will augment the Fourier transform expression so that we may rigorously differentiate under the integral.  Proceeding, we have

$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+2\pi i\xi}\,e^{2\pi i\xi x}\,d\xi\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-2\pi i \xi}{1+4\pi^2 \xi^2}\,e^{2\pi i\xi x}\,d\xi\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi \xi x)}{1+4\pi^2\xi^2}\,d\xi+2\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\xi\sin(2\pi \xi x)}{1+4\pi^2\xi^2}\,d\xi \\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\xi x)}{1+\xi^2}\,d\xi+\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\xi \sin(\xi x)}{1+\xi ^2}\,d\xi\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\xi x)}{1+\xi^2}\,d\xi+\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{((\xi^2+1)-1) \sin(\xi x)}{\xi(1+\xi ^2)}\,d\xi\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\xi x)}{1+\xi^2}\,d\xi+\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(\xi x)}{\xi}\,d\xi-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ \sin(\xi x)}{\xi(1+\xi ^2)}\,d\xi\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi }\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\xi x)}{1+\xi^2}\,d\xi+\frac1{2}\text{sgn}(x)-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ \sin(\xi x)}{\xi(1+\xi ^2)}\,d\xi\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, differentiation under the first integral is justified since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\xi \sin(\xi x)}{1+\xi^2}\,d\xi$ converges uniformly for all $|x|>\delta>0$.  Differentiation under the second integral is justified since the derivative of the integrand is absolutely integrable.

We split the procedure of differentiation into the two cases for which $x>0$ and $x<0$.  In both cases, we find that

$$\begin{align}
F'(x)&=-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\xi \sin(\xi x)}{1+\xi^2}\,d\xi-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\xi x)}{1+\xi ^2}\,d\xi\\\\
&=-F(x)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $F(x)=C^{+}e^{-x}$, for $x>0$ and $F(x)=C^- e^{-x}$ for $x<0$.

Now, note that as $x\to 0^+$, $F(x)\to 1$ while as $x\to 0^-$, $F(x)\to 0$.  We conclude that

$$F(x)=e^{-x}H(x)$$

where $H(x)$ is the heaviside function. And we are done!

Comment: Wonderful! I really appreciate that you showed how this can be done with real analysis.  Given the earlier hints provided, I learned how to do this using complex analysis and intend to share that answer as well. The different approaches provide more insight into what is going on.  I am studying the combinatorics of the orthogonal Sheffer polynomials, which arise in solutions to Schroedinger's equation. The moments are very fundamental numbers such as n! in this case. I am studying what it means for distributions to arise from such moments. Thank you for illuminating this process!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: I will add some notes that helped me understand your solution. After the first line you multiplied by $\frac{1-2\pi \xi}{1-2\pi \xi}$. Then you wrote out $e^{2\pi i \xi x}=\cos{2\pi i \xi x}+i \sin{2\pi i \xi x}$ and multiplied out, discarding the imaginary terms because the integral is real. You used the chain rule with $u=2\pi\xi$ which you renamed back to $\xi$. The factor $\xi$ in the numerator yielded an extra $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. After the fourth line you continued so as to get the seventh line where you could justify moving differentiation under the integral.

Comment: The seventh line is also where you show where the limits tend. The integral with cos tends to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}d\xi$ which by the chain rule with $\xi=\tan\theta$ and $d\xi=\sec^2\theta d\theta$ yields $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta = \pi$ which yields $\frac{1}{2}$.  Adding $\frac{1}{2}sgn(x)$ yields $1$ if $x>0$ and $0$ if $x<0$. Whereas the integral with sin is 0 as x approaches 0.  The observation that $F'(x)=-F(x)$ goes back to the fourth line.  This equation is the key to the whole approach to yield the $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Actually, I didn't discard the imaginary part because the integral is real.  I interpreted the integrals as principal values.  The integrands are odd and integate to zero.

Comment: Oh, thank you for correcting my mistake!

Comment: Of course.  You're quite welcome.