# Given Bell numbers as moments, derive the Poisson distribution

Tags: fourier-transform, poisson-distribution, bell-numbers

The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) (with $\lambda=1$) has probability mass function $\frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$ where $k\in\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$. Its moments are the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_n$, which count the possible partitions of a set with $n$ elements.

If I start with the Bell numbers and I suppose that they are the moments of some distribution, then how can I arrive at the Poisson distribution?

Let me give a similar problem that I am able to solve. Given moments $\mu_n=n!$, I can use the formula $\hat{w}(\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2\pi i)^n \mu_n}{n!}\xi^n$. This yields

$$\hat{w}(\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2\pi i)^n n!}{n!}\xi^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-2\pi i\xi)^n=\frac{1}{1-(-2\pi i \xi)}=\frac{1}{1+2\pi i\xi}$$

Then I can apply $w(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{w}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}d\xi$. The integral is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828849/how-to-integrate-int-infty-infty-frac112-pi-i-xie2-pi-i-xi-xd-x). The result is $w(x)=e^{-x}H(x)$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.

I want to do something similar to go from the Bell numbers to the Poisson distribution. In my example above, I make use of the Fourier transform. But I don't know what would work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question. I found this page helpful: [What is the Laplace Transform of the Poisson Distribution?](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1idizg/what_is_the_laplace_transform_of_the_poisson/)

I know that the generating function of the Bell numbers is $e^{e^t-1}$, or more generally, if each part of a partition contributes weight $\lambda$, it is $e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$. This is the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) $M_X(t)$, and as explained at the Wikipedia page, it is related to the Laplace transform of the probability density function $f_X(x)$ as follows: $M_X(t)=\mathcal{L}\{f_x\}(-t)$. So we could take the inverse Laplace transform. But we need a version that works with discrete functions. That is the [Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) where $z$ is a complex number but we can write $z=Ae^{it}$ so it is like the Laplace transform. We can proceed:

$e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}=e^{-\lambda}e^{e^t\lambda}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^t\lambda)^x}{x!}= e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}f_X(x) $

where $f_X(x)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$ and $x\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

So basically that gives the answer I want but I don't understand in what sense the transform is sensible, valid, meaningful, correct or not. I appreciate comments!

Edit: Here Robert Murray led me to understand what I want to say.

$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}f_X(x) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}p_x = \mathbb{E}(e^{Xt})$

where $X$ is any discrete random variable, which may take value $x\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ in the domain of this probability mass function $f_X(x)=p_x=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$. So we started with the generating function of the Bell numbers, and we have arrived at an explicit form of the Poisson distribution to express the expected value of $e^{Xt}$, which is a summary of all of the moments.

What have we achieved? We know that the Bell numbers $B_t(\lambda)$ count the partitions of a set of length $t$ where the weight $\lambda$ is given to each part. So now we can try to think of the Poisson distribution from this combinatorial perspective. The Poisson distribution is the norm for the orthogonality of the Charlier polynomials, whose coefficients also have a combinatorial interpretation.  Similarly, we can do so for other orthogonal Sheffer polynomials, which are important in solving Schroedinger's equation. So this gives a new way of investigating quantum physics, as I do [here](https://www.math4wisdom.com/wiki/Exposition/ResearchProgramFivesome).

Robert, thank you! I needed your help! I learned a lot!

Comment: The Transform is valid and meaningful. At the end, you have $\mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} f_X(k)$, where $X$ is any discrete random variable, which is the definition of a moment generating function. From this you obtain $f_X(x) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$ which is the p.m.f. of the poisson distribution. So, We have split you split the moment generating function into the original form. I think the only possible issue is you assumed the distribution was discrete, but it may be that the continuous function is non-invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential Generating function for the bell numbers is:
$$B(x) = e^{e^{x}-1}$$
You may recognize this as the moment generating function for the poisson distribution when $\lambda = 1$. Let me know if you want more hints.

Edit: You have severely overcomplicated this. The moment generating function of a random varible $x$ is defined as:
$$M_x(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^X]$$
If there exists a $\delta$ such that the function is finite for all $t \in (-\delta,\delta)$. Then, we only care about the values of the $n^{th}$ derivative with respect to $t$ when $t = 0$, which will give us our $n^{th}$ moment. In other words:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \frac{d^n}{dt^n} M_X(t)\big|_{t=0}$$
We also know that an Exponential Generating Function can give us the $n^{th}$ term of the series by taking the $n^{th}$ derivative and setting $x=0$, so:
$$B_n = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} B(x)\big|_{x=0}$$
Hence, we can conclude that the moment generating function for our random variable $X$ is:
$$M_x(t) = e^{e^{t}-1}$$
Because the $n^{th}$ derivative at $t=0$ gives us the $n^{th}$ moment and also the $n^{th}$ bell number.
And if two random variables, X and $Y \thicksim \text{Poi}(1)$ have the same moment generating function, they have the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Yes, I am aware of this generating function for the Bell numbers. But how would I proceed further?  I tried to use the expression that would work for a Schwartz function (but this is not a Schwartz function) $\hat{w}(\xi)=$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2\pi i)^nB_n}{n!}\xi^n $ $= e^{e^{-2\pi i\xi}-1} =$ e^{e^{(2\pi i)^{{-\xi}-1}}$  $ $= e^{1^{-\xi}-1}=e^{1-1}=e^0=1$  And then the inverse of the Fourier transform $w(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\pi i\xi x}d\xi$. But this is wrong! I appreciate your help!

Comment: I edited it with the rest, I think you have forgotten what these two things mean, so I just clarify the problem for you.

Comment: thank you for clarifying.  But are you supposing that we already know what the Poisson distribution is? I want to avoid that. Starting with the Bell numbers as moments, I want to construct (or recover) the Poisson distribution.  I am interested to see how that construction would work. That is my question. Given the moments, how can I construct the distribution (at least in this particular case)? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to the Moment-generating function. I did not know of that.

Comment: We do not know that it is a poisson distribution of $\lambda = 1$, but we do know what a poisson distribution of $\lambda = 1$ is. If we don't know what it is, the question is kind of meaningless. Given any sequence of moments, we would want to construct an exponential generating function that generates this sequence, simplify it, and then see if it matches to any known moment generating function for a random variable. If it matches to some moment generating function, then we would say that our distribution that produces these moments is that specific distribution.

Comment: what you say is very sensible.  But my question is how to make the construction.  I am trying to interpret the process going from moments to distributions. I can do this in some cases using the inverse of the Fourier transform. But I got stuck in this case, going from the Bell numbers to the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Every distribution of a random variable has a unique moment generating function, based on the type of distribution (Normal, Poisson, Binomial, etc.) and its parameters. For any poisson distribution the moment generating function is $M_X(t) = e^{\lambda (e ^{t} - 1)}$. Our exponential generating function is really really close to this, we just need to substitute $/lambda = 1$. To go from a sequence of moments to distributions, we want a function that creates the moments the same way the moment generating function does, which we can create the same way we make an exponential generating function.

Comment: You are correct. But is my question is how to derive the distribution. Without assuming it or knowing of it.

Comment: That is a meaningless question? If I don't know what a poisson distribution is defined as how am I supposed to say that the moments being bell numbers are a poisson distribution? Even if you could know that it follows the pmf of a poisson distribution (which realistically you can't), how would you know that this pmf is a poisson of $\lambda = 1$ if we don't know what a poisson of $\lambda = 1$ is.

Comment: I have edited it with what I think you are asking.

Comment: thank you for your edit. Thank you also for telling me about the terminology "moment generating function". I have likewise edited my question.  I think it is clearer now.